# Redirecting console to a string in a .NET program

Tags: c#, string, console

How can I redirect whatever is written to the console to be written into a string?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For your own process, [`Console.SetOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx) and redirect it to a TextWriter built on top of a string builder or memory stream. For a launched child process, use [`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx) when launching the process.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Console.SetOut ();`

Answer (score -1):

```
string consoleString = Console.ReadLine();
```